# Can't reenable virtual machine's (Fedora's) keyboard shortcuts after declining once

Tags: gnome-boxes

I'm running Ubuntu and I have installed Fedora 38 as a VM in Gnome boxes.

When I installed for the fist time some days ago, a window popped up asking if I'd allow the VM to change keyboard shortcuts, which I mistakenly declined.

Now, naturally, Fedora's shortcuts won't work. (For instance, when I hit the super key, Ubuntu's app will open, not Fedora's.) I reinstalled (and purged) `gnome-boxes` and its dependencies, but when I install Fedora now, the above-mentioned prompt regarding shortcuts never reappears and shortcuts won't work as a result.

Can anyone point out how I can enable a VM's keyboard shortcuts?